# Insert Unique Records, Update Duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, duplicates

I have two tables, TABLESource is where will i get the records to be inserted in TABLEDest,

now TABLESource can contain duplicate fields:

```
id  code    name
2   09  abc
3   10  uu
2   09  def
3   10  rr
2   09  gh
```

and i have to insert first all the unique records in the TABLEDest, the id+code is primary key (unique)

```
id  code    name
2   09  abc
3   10  uu
```

now, in the end, if the TABLESource found duplicate id and name, it must update the TABLEDest with the latest records found in the TABLESource with the same primary key (id_name)

```
id  code    name
2   09  gh
3   10  rr
```

I have no clue how to do that. Please help me. THanks :)

Comment: What version of MSSQL, there are better options in SQL2k5 and later.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the latest records found in the TableSource"? How do you define latest?

Comment: How do you know that `rr` is a later value than `uu`? What other column do you have to order the rows by?

Comment: based on their row position only. im using mssql2000

Comment: I'm sorry. There is no "row position" in SQL Server.

Comment: i mean just the ordering of the rows alone. duh

Comment: To expand a bit on @Mikael's comment, unless *you* specify a sort order, SQL Server is free to return the results in any order it sees fit. In theory, this means that the ordering of the results from executing a statement *without an explicit order by* can differ. You should not rely on the fact that in practise this (almost never) happens. If you have no column to order by, your requirement is *impossible to implement reliably*.

Comment: nvm, solved it already :) thanks anyways

Comment: @Blair Yumi - what solved it for you?

Comment: basically, got the logic from the 1st answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest iterating through your source table and for each row in the source:

```
Psudo Code:
//Get all source rows
query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEsource'
rows = database.get(query)

//Iterate through all source rows
for each rows as row{
    //Search dest table for a match    
    checkQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEDest WHERE id = '+row.id
    check = database.get(checkQuery)

    //If we do get a match
    if(check.rows > 0){

       //Update the relevant row
       query = 'UPDATE TABLEDest SET name = '+row.name+' WHERE id = '+check.id
       database.query(query)

    }else{

       //Otherwise, append a new row to the dest table
       query = 'INSERT INTO TABLEDest(id, code, name) '
              +'VALUES('+row.id+'. '+row.code+', '+row.name+')'
       database.query(query)

    }
}
```

This is psudo code, so directly copying and pasting won't work, but it should be enough for you to use your favorite flavor of language to make it happen.

Comment: tried this already, but it keeps on inserting the duplicate records because the Query on my source table returns only one result, but it keeps on inserting again and again

Comment: Are you actually iterating through the results from the source table? You should only be doing the comparison on the destination table and only comparing you key fields.

Comment: when inserting, i just iterate with the source table with WHERE condition. so it just have to return one time only, if i insert that code inside another iteration (comparing) it duplicates its insert method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no way to order the rows I choose to pick the min(name) as a value for the name column.

```
insert into TABLEDest
select id, code, min(name)
from TABLESource
group by id, code
```

Comment: i cant use rownumber() and over()

Comment: i cant use this exactly, because i'm inserting based on a dataset value